# i'm trying to export a process template using the API, but get the error: "This feature is disabled" how can I enable this feature?

Tags: azure-devops

When i try to export a process template i got the next response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "The feature is disabled. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.FeatureDisabledException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server",
    "typeKey": "FeatureDisabledException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7vqM.png)

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Your account is configured to use the [inheritance process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process), not the [XML process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops). Importing and exporting processes is for the XML process model.

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you are trying to use below API to **export work item process template**:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processadmin/processes/export/{id}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

However this API call are **only valid for fully customized processes** and **will not work with System or Inherited Custom processes**.

To customize **inherited processes**, you just need to do it in the web portal. It's no need and also not able to export the template by using above Rest API.

If you want to programmatically work with these processes.You can get, create, update, and delete processes defined for an organization using the [REST API, Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

More details, please kindly review our official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i will to try get and create the process template through API

Comment: Hi Juan Esteban Echavarria Osorio,  did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?